# Custom NSTableCellView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableviewcell

I want to make a NSTableView with customs NSTableCellView, here's what I've done so far :

AppDelegate.h :

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "TheView.h"

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate>

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;
@property (copy) NSMutableArray *tableContent;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

-(IBAction)addRow:(id)sender;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m :

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize tableContent;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    tableContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        tableContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    NSLog(@"%@",tableContent); //Here tableContent is empty
    return [tableContent count];
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSView *result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
    TheView *view = [tableContent objectAtIndex:row];
    result = view;
    return result;
}

-(IBAction)addRow:(id)sender {
    TheView *view = [[TheView alloc]init];
    [tableContent addObject:view];
    NSLog(@"%@",tableContent); //Here tableContent result with the correct number of objects
    [_tableView reloadData];
}
```

But when I try to add an object, nothing happens... TheView is a subclass of NSTableCellView, it's drawing a simple rect.
I've of course added NSTableViewDataSource and NSTableViewDelegate.

**UPDATE 2**
After further researches in my code, I found that in `numberOfRowsInTableView`, tableContent resulted empty or with the number of object I initialized my array with...

Answer (score 0):

The views your creating seem to have no size. You could try replacing the view initialization, and use `initWithFrame` instead of `init`

```
[[TheView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20)];
```

Also, you can try set in fame on the `viewForTableColumn` method.